# SQlite to MySQL migration for Seafile Server

Tags: mysql, windows, sqlite, seafile-server

I have successfully got Seafile Server fully working with HTTPS.
However I'm trying to migrate from SQLite to MySQL and everytime I try, the seafile server stops working.
I'm not sure what information to put here that yous will need but happy to provide what ever you need.
I followed this guide  [Deploy Seafile Windows Server With MySQL](http://manual.seafile.com/deploy_windows/deploy_with_mysql.html)

Its really frustrating, I dont understand why its not working. I also installed MySQL Workbench and I can see the seafile user with privileges and the databases populated with the tables.

Comment: Anybody? I'm stumped here.

Comment: What do you mean by "stops working"? Can't you start the server with './seafile.sh start'? Can't you start Seahub? Can't you access the website?

Answer (score 0):

Are there any messages in the logs?

Please look at the logs in /seafile/logs/

You will see an error message in seafile.log if you have problems with MySQL.

For example:

```
 ../common/seaf-db.c(123): Failed to get database connection: 
 Failed to connect to MySQL: Can't connect to MySQL server on '127.0.0.1' (107).
 http-server.c(761): DB error when check repo existence.
 Disconnected from daemon
```

I have done such migration already and it did work without problems.